# What are 'com.apple.access_ssh' and 'com.apple.access_screensharing'; can I delete them?

Tags: macos, security, permission, user-account

When I examine the list of users and groups on my machine (OSX 10.9) with `id` I get:

```
uid=501(Rax)
gid=20(staff)
groups=20(staff)
       103(Rax),
       12(everyone),
       61(localaccounts),
       80(admin),
       98(_lpadmin),
       33(_appstore),
       100(_lpoperator),
       204(_developer),
       398(com.apple.access_screensharing),
       399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

I don't (currently) have any sharing enabled. What are the last two groups and where did they come from? Can I delete them; if so how?

---

Using `sudo dscl  . -read /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh` I get:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
Comment:
 SSH Service ACL
GeneratedUID: XXX...
NestedGroups: XXX...
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 399
RealName:
 SSH Service ACL
RecordName: com.apple.access_ssh
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
```

And using `sudo dscl  . -read /Groups/com.apple.access_screensharing` I get:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
Comment:
 Screensharing Service ACL
GeneratedUID: XXX...
NestedGroups: XXX...
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 398
RealName:
 Screensharing Service ACL
RecordName: com.apple.access_screensharing
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
```

(Though I'm not sure what any of that means.)

Comment: Why do you want to delete them in the first place?

Comment: @patrix: That's what the "what are they" part of the question is about. Perhaps I don't. But I didn't have them before updating to 10.9 and migrating to a new machine, and they sure look like a way to access my machine remotely.

Comment: Groups are used to control access permissions to files/folders, they can not be used to login.

Comment: @patrix: So: I shouldn't delete them because there's no reason to might begin to answer the second part of the question.

Comment: This site doesn't work too well with several questions asked at once (in one post). Can you edit your question to either ask "what are these groups for" *or* "can I safely delete them"? The first would probably result in better answers...

Comment: When I did `id` It gave me ssh user.. When I then did `find / -uid ###` where the ### associated with that ssh user it seemed to indicate programs like Anti-Virus software is making use of them too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer correctly to the 1st question (and not wait the delay I would need to make a correct answer to 2nd question).

What are the groups:

```
   398(com.apple.access_screensharing),
   399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

for?

These groups are created to separate priviledges.

To be able to manage the access to the screen sharing setting,
you just need to be in group `398`.
You don't need to be `root`, you don't need to be in the group `wheel`.

This is a good security policy. This priviledges separation is a real
security improvment.

Answer (score 1):

The main admin user on my 10.9 VM is also part of both those groups, so I guess it's normal.

> Tests-Mac:~ test$ id
>   uid=501(test) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)

Membership in the `com.apple.access_screensharing` group seems to correspond to the user (or a group it's a member of) being included in this list:

[image]

When I created a new standard account, it was not a member of the `com.apple.access_screensharing` group by default, but after I added the account to the list above, it became a member of the group.

Similarly, membership in the `com.apple.access_ssh` group seems to correspond to the user being included in the list in the Remote Login section.